# How to do multiple searches (with logical OR) in WP_Query in hook pre_get_posts?

Tags: php, wp-query, hooks, search, pre-get-posts

Example:

`$query->set('s', 'foo bar');` - search `foo bar`

I want set search as `foo bar` OR `lorem ipsum dolor` OR `ping pong`

Comment: Could you give more details about the question, as it's now its really difficult to understand what you need. `s` searches in post title and alos in post content. You want pre get posts to always search for `foo bar`/'lorem ipsum dolor'/'ping pong'? or do you pass each one manualy, by url query for example?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I means that need to do so that posts are displayed that title/content contains `foo bar` or `lorem ipsum dolor` or `ping pong`

Comment: Is this inclusive, or exclusive? E.g. if something has `foo bar` in it can it also have `ping pong`? Or would that disqualify it? Keep in mind that WordPress' built in search functionality is extremely basic/simple, if you want more advanced search functionality you should look into software or services such as elastic search

Comment: @TomJNowell this question has already been resolved

Comment: just because you marked an answer as accepted, doesn't mean other people can't leave their own answers that might be better, or different. The accepted answer can still be changed. Clarifying the question also helps other people who might have the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'bt_search_posts');

function bt_search_posts ($query) {
    // the posts ids that contain foo bar OR lorem ipsum dolor OR ping pong
    $posts_ids = [];

    // get the current query vars
    $query_vars = $query->query_vars;

    // loop each term we want to search and if found, add the post id into the array
    foreach (['foo bar', 'lorem ipsum dolor', 'ping pong'] as $search_term) {
        // add the search term to the query vars
        $query_vars['s']      = $search_term;

        // we only need posts ids so we set that
        $query_vars['fields'] = 'ids';

        // loop through found posts, if not found we will have a empty array so no problem
        foreach (get_posts($query_vars) as $post_id) {
            $posts_ids[] = $post_id;
        }
    }

    // set post__in to the posts ids that we found that matched the search terms we provided
    if (!empty($posts_ids)) $query->set('post__in', $posts_ids);
}
```

I have no idea where you want to run this query so you need to add the proper checks so you won't interfere with other `WP_Query`, like the main WordPress query and the like.

A good starting check would be

```
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    // code here
}
```

But if you already have one that works best for you, use it =]

Comment: This will cause an infinite loop as `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` internally which triggers this filter

Comment: thank you very much